# 3rd party Component and COM Components

Tags: vb6

How to differenciate between 3rd party Component and COM Components in existing VB6.0 applications?

Comment: Can you clarify what you think the difference is between the two? Maybe an example?

Answer (score 1):

Third party components often **are** COM components so I'm not sure what you mean.

- Are you trying to distinguish between third-party components and components that come with Visual Basic? You could consult the [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx) of Microsoft components which are currently supported on Windows 7 and 2008. If your component isn't listed there, it's *probably* a third-party one. **EDIT** although it could also be an older Microsoft component that they no longer support.
- Are you trying to distinguish between COM components and ordinary DLLs? Code in an ordinary DLL is accessed through a `Declare` statement **EDIT** and sometimes via a [special typelib](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143258).

Thanks to Bob for the useful comments which I have now edited into my answer.

Comment: If not in the "supported" list it might be an older component that shipped with VB6 too.  Non-COM DLLs can also be used via typelibs instead of Declare.  This yields performance improvements and reduces symbol table clutter in the compiler, which has some large but real limits on the number of items you can define.

Comment: Also, some libraries can be used *both ways* (StdCall calls or COM interfaces) even within one program.  A good example is Shell32.dll.

Comment: I'm still unclear what the question is really asking myself.  Is it perhaps asking the differences among the VB6 runtime's intrinsic controls, Microsoft supplied ActiveX controls, and 3rd party ActiveX controls?